# Pydub: How to ave audio after convert it to aac?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pydub

I am using django admin form to recieve a audio input, and I am trying to convert it into `aac` format with `pydub`.
I have installed `ffmpeg` in my system and also added `pydub` and `ffmpeg-python` as dependencies.

Here is the django ModelAdmin:

```
class AudioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('file', 'bit_rate', 'format')
    list_display = ('id', 'file', 'bit_rate', 'format', 'content_type')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        audio_file = form.cleaned_data['file']
        _, file_extension = os.path.splitext(audio_file.name)
        curr_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file=audio_file, format=file_extension.replace('.', ''))
        new_audio = curr_audio.export(out_f=audio_file.name, format="aac")
        obj.file = new_audio
        obj.save()
```

I am still getting this error while converting an mp3 file in `aac` format.

```
    raise CouldntEncodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntEncodeError: Encoding failed. ffmpeg/avlib returned error code: 1
Command:['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'wav', '-i', '/var/folders/8g/230x9vx55p7c0bdwx0cmzx9r0000gq/T/tmpxaetjjk0', '-f', 'aac', '/var/folders/8g/230x9vx55p7c0bdwx0cmzx9r0000gq/T/tmpa3ae8nn1']
Output from ffmpeg/avlib:
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from '/var/folders/8g/230x9vx55p7c0bdwx0cmzx9r0000gq/T/tmpxaetjjk0':
  Duration: 00:03:14.72, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
[NULL @ 0x7fe40da072c0] Requested output format 'aac' is not a suitable output format
/var/folders/8g/230x9vx55p7c0bdwx0cmzx9r0000gq/T/tmpa3ae8nn1: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search I came across this github issue https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/363. `format="adts"` works when you are trying to convert audio from mp3 or wav to aac or m4a audio.